# create chart similar to this using R and radarchart

Tags: r, radar-chart

I am just wondering if I am able to create a chart similar to the one below using radarchart and r?  I just found radarchart, but I wasn't able to make it very far before getting confused.  Would the column names be every 5 degrees or whatever the chart is separated at?  So would the data frame have to look something like this?

```
 mph         80     75     70     65     60     55     50     45     40 etc..
 20            
 40
 50            5
 60                 
 80                                                     8      7       6
 90                                9      9
 100
```

[image]

Comment: Taking a look at [the package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/radarchart/vignettes/preparingData.html) may help.